# What's the relationship between Solomon's Temple and Christians?

Tags: ancient-history, religion, christianity, jews, bible

An Evangelical-Pentecostal church has built a huge replica of Solomon's Temple in Brazil. But why Solomon's Temple? What does it have to do with Jesus Christ and the Christian faith?
It's very odd to me that they are embracing elements that seem more Jewish than Christian like Solomon's Temple, the Ark of the Covenant and a kippah when preaching. But maybe my idea of Christian traditions is too modern. Have these elements ever been part of any Christian faith?

Further information about this replica: It's from the Universal Church of the Kingdom of God that operates in more than 100 countries and was even banned from some African countries. The owner is Edir Macedo, that also appears on Forbes's list of billionaires. He spent 300 M on the construction. [Here's the story](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/07/25/world/americas/temple-in-brazil-appeals-to-a-surge-in-evangelicals.html) as covered by *The New York Times*. [Here's the inauguration video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMkLVl2pghM), where you can also see how they have used the religious elements I've talked about.

Comment: I see the historical elements of your question (especially the last line), so I don't think this should be closed as off-topic. But I bet you'd get a very good answer over at Christianity.SE

Comment: I had searched for religion.se but I didn't find anything. It didn't strike my mind that SE would have specific community for different religions. Thank you. I'll also post this question there.

Comment: With some work, this could be a good question. Keep in mind though that Christianity.SE prefers to focus on what specific Christian groups teach or do. Your question at the end is good for that purpose; focus on that (and avoid questions of validity or truth).

Comment: Indeed. I have changed the question a little bit.

Comment: Although there are trivial historical elements, the relationship between Judaism and Christianity can be understood through religious techniques more than through historical analysis.  Historically Christianity emerges from Judaism and consequently the Christian tradition inherits the Jewish tradition.   You may also wish to consider the mythology of the Freemasons in your study of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Since Christianity believes that Christ is the Messiah that completes the Jewish prophecy, they also view the entire corpus of Old Testament history as part of Christian history - which is why it makes up half the Bible.  As a major construction in the past built to specifications given by God, Solomon's temple is thus of historical interest to Christians.  Building a duplicate might be extreme, but it isn't strange that a Christian sect would look back on Old Testament events like Moses, the Ark, or Solomon.

Comment: Rather more than half, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that the [Third Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Temple) is necessary for the return of Christ appears to be related to [Dispensationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispensationalism), which Wikipedia describes as a "Christian evangelical, futurist, Biblical interpretation". [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dispensationalism&oldid=673508393):

> Dispensationalists believe that the nation of Israel is distinct from the Christian Church,[2]:322 and that God has yet to fulfill his promises to national Israel. These promises include the land promises, which in the future world to come result in **a millennial kingdom and Third Temple where Christ, upon his return, will rule the world from Jerusalem[3] for a thousand years**. In other areas of theology, dispensationalists hold to a wide range of beliefs within the evangelical and fundamentalist spectrum.[1]:13 (emphasis mine)